# is it possible to use external library for android studio project layout?

Tags: android, html

just a novice. I am just wondering if it is possible to use my pre-designed css library as android studio layout.and also if there is any way to take control of app by using online library so if i change the library the look of installed apps should change like happens in HTML document. something like

```
<link rel="stylesheed" src="http://mysite/library/style.css">
<script src="mysite/library/script.js">
```

i know its bit dumb but i am just curious to know.

Comment: This is usually a bad idea with an installed app.  People don't always update their apps.  If you update the version online, its unlikely you've fully tested those changes on older versions and ensured it works.  The app and all the resources needed for it to run should be shipped with the app.  And if you mean to use your css in a layout.xm file:  no.  They don't use CSS.  And even if they did, they're precompiled, not interpreted at runtime.

Comment: You can obviously use a Webview but can't use a CSS Library explicitly as also @GabeSechan mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design your layout by html by this css, js. Then load html to a WebView of Android Native. To do this you have to keep this html, css & js in asset folder. But if you need more interaction such as api call or other then you can use PhoneGap.